# outlook add-in prevent creating duplicate folders

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have an Outlook add-in that, on start-up, tries to create a sub-folder under Outbox folder if one doesn't already exist. The issue occurs when I install the add-in on two different computers. After installing and running the add-in on one computer, if I install on another one and open up Outlook, the add-in immediately finds that no such sub-folder exists since Outlook hasn't finished syncing the local data-store with the server. It now creates a new duplicate sub-folder and after Outlook syncing, I end up having two sub-folders with the same name. What's the best way to prevent this? Currently I'm thinking of one of these approaches:

- Somehow creating a local-only sub-folder so that it doesn't sync with the server. Each install on a different computer would have a separate sub-folder. This would work fine for the purpose of my add-in. Is this possible?
- Check server side to see if the sub-folder is already created, if so then do nothing. However, I don't know how to perform this check using OOM via C#.

Answer (score 0):

There is not way to create a local only folder in a cached store, but you can always add a PST store to the profile and store your data there.

You can open the parent folder in the online mode using Extended MAPI or Redemption, but what do you do if there is no connection at the time your cod runs?

Comment: Good point about requiring the connection, in that case I can let it fail graciously without affecting my add-in much. However, could you elaborate more on the first point about adding a PST store to the profile?

Comment: Also, even using MAPI to check the subfolder in online mode, I realized it still wouldn't work 100%. If two different computers start their Outlook for the first time simultaneously, they will both create subfolders and then after syncing will end up with duplicate folders again.

Comment: A PST store can be added using Namespace.AddStore/AddStoreEx.